# How do you tell what index is being used in SAS proc sql? Is there an explain equivalent?

Tags: sas

Is there an equivalent to EXPLAIN in SAS Proc SQL?  From Google searches I've done, it doesn't seem like it.

Actually, what I really need to know is how to tell if an index was used during a JOIN or which index the query ended up using.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OPTIONS MSGLEVEL=I;`
will tell you when an index is used (and which), for SQL or data step.

Example:

```
data class(index=(sex));
set sashelp.class;
run;
options msglevel=i;
proc sql feedback;
select * from class where sex='M';
quit;
```

FEEDBACK and STIMER are useful PROC SQL options that will also give you more information about the query you wrote ( http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001360938.htm)

Edit:
https://communities.sas.com/thread/14072?start=0&tstart=0

Apparently there IS an explain option, though it's undocumented and still a work in progress.  See the link for more details.

Comment: In addition you may also want to use PROC SQL _METHOD; with that method you can see when SAS is sorting things in the background. For inner joins, if one of tables being joined can fit into memory, most of the time SAS does a Hash Join which is way quicker then DATA STEP or using indexes.